# How to link 3 columns together in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have 3 columns in a Google sheets tab.

Two of the columns are fed into from another tab (Sheet1) by the formulas `=Sheet1!A2:A` and `=Sheet1!B2:B`.

I am facing a problem when the 2 columns from `sheet1` are sorted, the third column from `sheet2` does not stay aligned with the other two and throws off my entire sheet's analysis. Is there a way to link the 3 columns together so when I sort from `sheet1`, all 3 columns from `sheet2` are sorted and not just the first 2 that are being fed into from `sheet1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. Sheets is not a relational database in which rows between sheets will remain linked.

What you can do is to work everything in a Master sheet so everything is sort together, or continue with your system but never "really" sorting your Sheet1. Instead, in any of both cases, you can use Filter Views. Filter views affect the way each user sees the information without altering the other users' views. That way you could just hide columns in Filter View in a single Master Sheet and everyone works in just one sheet; or "sort" the Master Sheet only when you're inside the Filter View, so the connected data always remain in the same rows.

I suggest you consider this possibility. Other ways are via scripts, which could be a headache by implementing it, always syncing and checking every kind of modification, sorting issue and more. Hope it's useful! There are many tutorials and documentation online; here you have just one as [example](https://blog.golayer.io/google-sheets/google-sheets-filter-view#:%7E:text=Hide%20Columns&text=Simply%20select%20the%20column%20you,Choose%20%E2%80%9CHide%20column%E2%80%9D.)